# How to save hidden data in Android Menu

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I make a menu of visited links in my Android app (history). In the items of history menu ***historySubmenu*** I show only visited links titles (from *WebHistoryItem::getTitle*).

I would like to save an urls (*WebHistoryItem::getUrl*) in the menu items in order to retreive them when particular item is choosen.

How to do it?

---

Hope this would be more clear.

Here is my code for constructing menu of visited pages:

```
WebBackForwardList wbfList = webview.copyBackForwardList();
historySubmenu.clear();
for (int i = wbfList.getSize() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
   WebHistoryItem current = wbfList.getItemAtIndex(i);
   historySubmenu.add(current.getTitle());
   // current.getUrl(); ???
}
```

The question is how to save each url in each item for use usl when item is pressed?

Or how to assosiate item of this menu with url?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, you are asking way too much.  Break your problem down into smaller issues.